# Trouble with inputs using a while loop

Tags: c, variables, global, local, cs50

```
int towerh;
do{
    printf ("give me an integer between 1 and 23 and I will make a tower");
    int towerh = GetInt();
}while (towerh < 1 || towerh > 23);
```

I'm trying to make this code block loop as long as `towerh` is not between 1 and 23. I keep getting errors saying that the variable needs to be initialized.

I'm sure this is a small thing but I have no clue how to assess or correct it in C.

Comment: 'int towerh;
    do{
        printf ("give me an integer between 1 and 23 and I will make a tower");
        towerh = GetInt();
    }while (towerh < 1 || towerh > 23);'

Comment: You should probably add tag of cs50

Comment: The trouble is you have two variables called `towerh`, one declared in the body of the loop, and one outside.  The loop condition tests the variable defined outside the loop, but the value read by `GetInt()` is assigned to the variable defined inside the loop.  That goes out of scope at the close brace.  You should simply drop the `int` inside the loop to assign to the variable defined outside the loop.  That's what Daulton Sink illustrated — but didn't exactly explain.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `int towerh;` to `int towerh = 0;`. That's called initializing a variable, and usually C compilers hate when you miss it.

Also, you create `towerh` again and again in your loop, and I would suggest `scanf` over the not-mentioned `GetInt`, so you can end with:

```
int towerh = 0;
do {
    printf("Give me an integer between 1 and 23 and I will make a tower: ");
    scanf("%d", &towerh);
} while (towerh < 1 || towerh > 23);
```

Comment: after trying that I get an error declaration shadows local variable

Comment: you tried the full code or just the initialization? shadowed variable means you create a variable under the same name again in your code, like you did with `int towerh` inside the loop

Comment: just the initialization i got it fixed now thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Code has 2 `towerh;`.  The first one is never set

```
int towerh;  // 1st, never initialized nor assigned.
do{
    printf ("give me an integer between 1 and 23 and I will make a tower");
    int towerh = GetInt(); // 2nd, not the same object as the outer towerh

//      v----v        v----v  Uses the 1st towerh
}while (towerh < 1 || towerh > 23);
```

Instead only use 1.

```
int towerh;  // One and only towerh
do{
    printf ("give me an integer between 1 and 23 and I will make a tower");
    // int towerh = GetInt();
    towerh = GetInt();
}while (towerh < 1 || towerh > 23);
```